# 'make' remains frozen during 4.6 installation on my Windows laptop

Tags: omnet++

I try to install Omnet++ in order to make a student project based on spacecraft communications.

I have Windows 10 on my laptop ASUS (Pentium 2.16GHz, RAM 2Go).
I download the "4.6 win32" release.
I follow the install guide but after the 'make' command :

```
 => after 1 hour, the process was always blocked in this sequence :
    MSGC: sim_std.msg
```

I try to install it on an other laptop with win XP and I have the same behaviour.

I try to install on a 'normal' PC (a toure with win 10) and it works !

I think that something is missing on my laptop but what ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution. That is a Windows problem.
You should go here :  "Control Panel \ User Accounts \ User Accounts" and disactive all.

It works !